# Ruby methods() method

Tags: ruby

I want to understand how Ruby method `methods()` work.
I tried to Google with "ruby methods" but it's not what i need.
Also i've seen ruby-doc.org, but i didn't find this method.

Can you expain me how it works in details or give me a link?

### Update

I experimented with `methods()` method and got such results:

#### 'lab rat' code

```
class First
  def first_instance_mymethod
  end
  def self.first_class_mymethod
  end
end
class Second < First
  def second_instance_mymethod
  end
  def self.second_class_mymethod
  end
end
```

#### Work with Classes

```
#returns available methods list for class and ancestors
puts Second.methods.grep(/mymethod/)
  # => second_class_mymethod
  # => first_class_mymethod

#returns Class methods list for current class only 
puts Second.methods(false)
  # => second_class_mymethod
```

#### Work with Objects

```
obj = Second.new
def obj.obj_singleton_mymethod
end

#returns available methods list for object and ancestors
puts obj.methods.grep(/mymethod/)
  # => second_instance_mymethod
  # => first_instance_mymethod

#returns current object class methods
puts obj.methods(false)
  # => obj_singleton_mymethod
```

Comment: it just gives you an array of methods defined for object you're calling .methods for. what exactly is not clear to you?

Comment: What isn't clear is that the methods method works fine when you try it out in Ruby 1.9.3 but it does not appear in the docs!  So annoying!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure why it's not in the ruby 1.9 docs (it seems to still be in the code), but you can see the documentation in the 1.8.7 docs: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/Object.html#M000032

Basically, in ruby 1.9 it just returns a list of the symbols (names) for all the methods in a given class and its ancestors. (ruby 1.8 it returned a list of strings)

Answer (score 5):

The  accepted answer misses a slight point. A fuller answer was given in the comment by keymone - .methods returns an array of symbols being names of all the methods defined on the given *instance*. For example:

```
irb(main):012:0> object = ""
=> ""
irb(main):013:0> object.instance_eval("def foo;:bar;end")
=> nil
irb(main):014:0> object.methods.include?(:foo)
=> true
irb(main):016:0> "".methods.include?(:foo)
=> false
```

Comment: but it contains link with method description

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Ruby 2.2.5 and I am unfortunately not getting this to work when passed false any longer. I do remember back on older versions of Ruby, passing false to this method used to return only the class-level methods.

However, as of Ruby 2.2.5, here's what I'm getting

```
class Thingy < ApplicationRecord
  def hello

  end
end

class Apple < Thingy
  def self.goodbye

  end


  def booty

  end
end
```

results:

```
2.2.5 :001 > a = Thingy.new
 => #<Thingy id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
2.2.5 :002 > a.methods(false)
 => [] 
2.2.5 :003 > b = Apple.new
 => #<Apple id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
2.2.5 :004 > b.methods(false)
 => [] 
2.2.5 :005 > Apple.methods(false)
 => [:attribute_type_decorations, :_validators, :defined_enums, :goodbye] 
2.2.5 :006 > Thingy.methods(false)
 => [:attribute_type_decorations, :_validators, :defined_enums] 
2.2.5 :007 >
```

the only time passing false returns anything interesting to me is to examine class-level methods only (those that start with `self.`) Otherwise it seems to not be helpful anymore.